# Perl: Accessing and handling objects in an array

Tags: arrays, perl, big-ip

I try to handle the following Array which was generated by `get_pool_member_object_status_($pool)`

from http://search.cpan.org/~ltp/BigIP-iControl/lib/BigIP/iControl.pm#get_pool_member_object_status_($pool)

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        bless( [
                 bless( {
                          'member' => bless( {
                                             'address' => '192.168.100.141',
                                             'port' => '80'
                                           }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' ),
                          'object_status' => bless( {
                                                    'availability_status' => 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN',
                                                    'status_description' => 'Pool member is available',
                                                    'enabled_status' => 'ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED'
                                                  }, 'LocalLB::ObjectStatus' )
                        }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus' ),
                 bless( {
                          'member' => bless( {
                                             'address' => '192.168.100.142',
                                             'port' => '80'
                                           }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' ),
                          'object_status' => bless( {
                                                    'availability_status' => 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN',
                                                    'status_description' => 'Pool member is available',
                                                    'enabled_status' => 'ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED'
                                                  }, 'LocalLB::ObjectStatus' )
                        }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus' ),
                 bless( {
                          'member' => bless( {
                                             'address' => '192.168.100.143',
                                             'port' => '80'
                                           }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' ),
                          'object_status' => bless( {
                                                    'availability_status' => 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN',
                                                    'status_description' => 'Pool member is available',
                                                    'enabled_status' => 'ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED'
                                                  }, 'LocalLB::ObjectStatus' )
                        }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus' ),
                 bless( {
                          'member' => bless( {
                                             'address' => '192.168.100.144',
                                             'port' => '80'
                                           }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' ),
                          'object_status' => bless( {
                                                    'availability_status' => 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN',
                                                    'status_description' => 'Pool member is available',
                                                    'enabled_status' => 'ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED'
                                                  }, 'LocalLB::ObjectStatus' )
                        }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus' )
               ], 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus[]' )
      ]
    ];
```

I couldn't figure out how this should work. I tried several examples from perldsc. The examples there mostly concern ARRAYS OF HASHES. But the above array is...? I don't even know what kind of array this is. Can someone point me in the right direction?

So for example how do I access the `"object_status"->"availability_status"` of a  `"member"->"address"`

Thx simbabque. This is the output I get from `Data::Printer:`

```
[
[0] [
    [0] LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus[]  {
        public methods (0)
        private methods (0)
        internals: [
            [0] LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus,
            [1] LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus,
            [2] LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus,
            [3] LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus
        ]
    }
]
```

]

Comment: It looks like an array of objects of type 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus[]' that contains an array of objects of type 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus'

Comment: Indeed, data structures that have a `bless` attached to them when dumped with Data::Dumper are objects. If you don't know what kind of methods those have, use [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer). It will tell you all about the objects, including inheritance, values and the methods it can do. You might need to fiddle with the options to get it to display them at that level of depths, but that's trivial.

Comment: I tried to understand where those classes come from and started reading [the source of BigIP::iControl](https://metacpan.org/source/LTP/BigIP-iControl-0.098/lib/BigIP/iControl.pm#L518). **Careful, maybe this is NSFW!**

Comment: Do you have access to a BigIP Perl manual? That would tell you how to use the API. The docs says "Unless you feel like playing with Data::Dumper on a rainy Sunday afternoon, consider using get_pool_member_statistics_stringified method."

Comment: I now think those classes all inherit from SOAP::Lite and it's data object classes somehow. There's a type map in the source above that very informative yet explicit comment. So those objects should have methods along the lines of `get_member`, `get_object_status` or `get_status_description`.

Comment: @Kusalananda can you add a link to that quote? That guy is really good at writing entertaining documentation. Never mind. Found it.

Comment: It's on the page you linked to yourself. The `get_all_pool_member_statistics` method is analogous to `get_pool_member_statistics` it says, and the quote is in the description of that method.

Comment: Whenever you are unsure about the data structure type, use `ref` in perl.
`print ref($obj);` so that will tell you that this is array and then you know that this is an arrayref, Now you could access the structure with `print Dumper($obj->[0]);`

Comment: some sample code in dealing with the iControl objects is available in the DevCentral codeshare: https://devcentral.f5.com/codeshare. A good example for your situation is here: https://devcentral.f5.com/codeshare/enable-disable-pool-member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to access the  `'availability_status'` and `'address'`
I didn't traverse this whole object but with this code I am able to print the required fields.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my $obj = [
      [
        bless( [
                 bless( {
                          'member' => bless( {
                                             'address' => '192.168.100.141',
                                             'port' => '80'
                                           }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' ),
                          'object_status' => bless( {
                                                    'availability_status' => 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN',
                                                    'status_description' => 'Pool member is available',
                                                    'enabled_status' => 'ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED'
                                                  }, 'LocalLB::ObjectStatus' )
                        }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus' ),
                 bless( {
                          'member' => bless( {
                                             'address' => '192.168.100.142',
                                             'port' => '80'
                                           }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' ),
                          'object_status' => bless( {
                                                    'availability_status' => 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN',
                                                    'status_description' => 'Pool member is available',
                                                    'enabled_status' => 'ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED'
                                                  }, 'LocalLB::ObjectStatus' )
                        }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus' ),
                 bless( {
                          'member' => bless( {
                                             'address' => '192.168.100.143',
                                             'port' => '80'
                                           }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' ),
                          'object_status' => bless( {
                                                    'availability_status' => 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN',
                                                    'status_description' => 'Pool member is available',
                                                    'enabled_status' => 'ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED'
                                                  }, 'LocalLB::ObjectStatus' )
                        }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus' ),
                 bless( {
                          'member' => bless( {
                                             'address' => '192.168.100.144',
                                             'port' => '80'
                                           }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' ),
                          'object_status' => bless( {
                                                    'availability_status' => 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN',
                                                    'status_description' => 'Pool member is available',
                                                    'enabled_status' => 'ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED'
                                                  }, 'LocalLB::ObjectStatus' )
                        }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus' )
               ], 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberObjectStatus[]' )
      ]
    ];

print Dumper($obj->[0]->[0]->[0]->{member}->{address});
print Dumper($obj->[0]->[0]->[0]->{object_status}->{availability_status});
print Dumper($obj->[0]->[0]->[1]->{member}->{address});
print Dumper($obj->[0]->[0]->[1]->{object_status}->{availability_status});
print Dumper($obj->[0]->[0]->[2]->{member}->{address});
print Dumper($obj->[0]->[0]->[2]->{object_status}->{availability_status});
print Dumper($obj->[0]->[0]->[3]->{member}->{address});
print Dumper($obj->[0]->[0]->[3]->{object_status}->{availability_status});
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = '192.168.100.141';
$VAR1 = 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN';
$VAR1 = '192.168.100.142';
$VAR1 = 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN';
$VAR1 = '192.168.100.143';
$VAR1 = 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN';
$VAR1 = '192.168.100.144';
$VAR1 = 'AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN';
```

Hope this helps and now you should be able to traverse this data structure with loops.